# can raiden network be used on ethereum PoA(proof of Authority)?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, raiden

https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden

can raiden network be used on ethereum PoA(proof of Authority) ? If it can , how to use it?

Please help.